# How to correctly debug web applications on local IIS 7.5 with VS 2010 Beta2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, iis-7.5

I'm sort of new to developing Asp.net webapplication projects while running them on a local IIS. Till now I used the 'Use Visual Studio Development Server' option. 
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.

**Edit: less complex sample code**

Following code sample:

```
        List<string> _list = new List<string>();
        _list.Add("asd");
        _list.Add("asd2");
        _list.Add("asd3");
```

Now I want to debug / step through some line of codes with **_list**.
While using 'Use Visual Studio Development Server' I can see the contents of **_list** in the quick watch.
If I select 'Use Local IIS Web server' and debug through the same piece of code, the quickwatch tries to display me the same values by showing me a spinning wheel for about 10 seconds with a resulting '**Function evalutation disabeld because a previous function evalution timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evalution**' message.

Afterwards I get a windows error dialog with '**Unhandeld win32 exception occured in w3wp.exe [844] The Just-In Time debugger was launched without necessary security permission**..'

I do run Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 as Administrator. I start debugging by pressing F5. It seems that I can't really debug this way. Do I somehow have to attach the VS debuggerto the IIS process? If yes, how to do so?

What am I doing wrong, and how to solve it?

And by the way, is that erroneous behaviour new in VS 2010? I've never expierencied that in VS 2008.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you have "webcompanion" by Lavasoft installed on your machine? Removing said software solved this problem for me.

Comment: Sorry, I can't exactly remember since I had the issue over 6 years ago, but I don't think that I installed anything from Lavasoft.

Comment: It's usually installed with other software such as Ad-Aware. Removing this fixed the problem for me and some others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. After enabling Windows Authentification for my Website in the IIS it worked. Hope this helps anybody in the future.

Comment: I've been trying to find an answer to the same question for a few weeks now. Debugging without viewing object collections has been miserable. You are a life saver - Thanks! Thread is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028355/visual-studio-2010-viewing-lists-during-debug-results-in-timeout/4110614#4110614 if you want credit/points

Comment: I'm glad I could help you and I'm also taking your offer =)

Answer (score 3):

> [**Just-In-Time debugging**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx) is a
>   feature that launches the Visual
>   Studio debugger automatically when a
>   program, running outside Visual
>   Studio, encounters a fatal error.

- One one hand it is an indication that
  your process is crashing due to some
  error.

Try disabling **JIT Debugger**. I have not used VS 2010 RC but process in VS2008 are as follows.

**Tools** -> **Options** -> **Debugging** -> **Just-In-time** and then uncheck the all just in time checks. Click okay.

---

Hope this helps