# Visual Studio 2010 - Viewing lists during debug results in timeout

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to debug a project, suddenly I'm running into an issue where enumerating any object collections results in a timeout if I try to view it.

If I run the program normally I have no issues. If I try to view any collection, such as a list, I get a timeout error and the whole thing bombs out.

I thought something might be going on with one of my more complex collections so I tried creating just a normal list of strings as follows...

```
List<string> blah = new List<string>{"fsdf","fsdg","Gt","gsersg","ser","gersgxdrsd"};
```

The same thing happens. I can hover over the object, I can even see the object count, however if I view the collection it dies.

I've ensured that the project/class library is in debug mode, disabled all extensions, restarted the system, tried percusive maintnence - nothing has worked.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm completely losing my mind here.

---

I should also mention that this is a web application, I didn't notice before but a w3wp debug window pops up after I stop debugging. Sorry to leave out important info - was too frustrated to think straight when I wrote the post. I can still execute my code normally, and while debugging. I can examine all other objects without issue, it is only looking at collections in the watch window (or by hovering) that breaks.

Comment: This doesn't happen with anybody else's install of VS2010.  Beyond seriously lacking hardware, there is no obvious diagnostic from your question.  Time for a new machine, perhaps.

Comment: My work computer isn't as fast as I'd like, but it is only a bit over year old. The problem started today and there have been no major hardware or software changes. It also only pauses for about 5 - 10 seconds before giving me a timeout so I don't think it is a true execution time issue. Although a new computer couldn't hurt :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [How to correctly debug web applications on local IIS 7.5 with VS 2010 Beta2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303926/how-to-correctly-debug-web-application-on-local-iis-7-5-with-vs-2010-beta2/2320087#2320087)